# Trouble model binding a JSON array to a List in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having trouble model binding a JSON array to a C# list in MVC 3.

I have an object called a `DockState`. It looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class DockState
{
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public bool Collapsed { get; set; }
    public string DockZoneID { get; set; }
    public int ExpandedHeight { get; set; }
    public Unit Height { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public Unit Left { get; set; }
    public bool Pinned { get; set; }
    public bool Resizable { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Unit Top { get; set; }
    public string UniqueName { get; set; }
    public Unit Width { get; set; }
}
```

My action method accepts a list of dock states, like this:

```
public JsonResult SaveDockStates(List<DockState> dockStates)
```

On the client I am building an array of JSON objects that contain all the same properties as the C# `DockState` object. I am then assigning this array to a JSON object of its own with the property of the argument in the action method, like this:

```
function get_allDockStates()
{
    var allRadDocks = []; // declare array.
    var allRadControls = $telerik.radControls; // use telerik API to obtain all controls.

    // loop through all telerik controls.
    for (var i = 0; i < allRadControls.length; i++)
    {
        var element = allRadControls[i];

        // Check if control is a rad dock element.
        if (Telerik.Web.UI.RadDock && element instanceof Telerik.Web.UI.RadDock)
        {
            // Build a JSON object containing the same properties as the C# DockState
            // object. Leaving out a couple that should just be null anyway. Add new
            // JSON object to array.
            Array.add(allRadDocks,
            {
                UniqueName: element._uniqueName,
                DockZoneID: element._dockZoneID,
                Width: element._width,
                Height: element._height,
                ExpandedHeight: element._expandedHeight,
                Top: element._top,
                Left: element._left,
                Resizable: element._resizable,
                Closed: element._closed,
                Collapsed: element._collapsed,
                Pinned: element._pinned,
                Title: element._title,
                Index: element._index
            });
        }
    }
    // Return the array.
    return allRadDocks;
}

// This function is fired by the rad dock controls when they are moved.
function positionChanged(sender, e)
{
    // obtain the array of dock states.
    var dockStates = get_allDockStates();
    // Make ajax call to MVC action method to save dock states.
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: { dockStates: dockStates },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/AjaxServices/DashboardService/SaveDockStates'
    });
}
```

Unfortunately something rather odd happens when the AJAX call is made. It hits the action method and my `List<DockState>` does have items in it.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/dockStateListInstantiated.jpg

However, the items in the list are all default. Meaning all their values are the default values, not the ones submitted in the request.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/dockStatesDefaultValues.jpg

I'm not sure why the list contains the correct number of items, but all items appear to be nothing more than instantiated. Their properties were not set to the values in the JSON array. The request definitely contains the right data, as shown here:

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/dockStatesFormData.jpg

Am I doing something wrong? Is the form data formatted incorrectly? Is there a problem with the default model binder?

#### Update (testing Darin Dimitrov's answer)

I discovered that JSON was being overridden by an unused old script. I have removed and now `JSON.stringify` is working fine. Here is the request payload.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/dockStatesJsonStringify.jpg

Much better. However now when I am debugging my list has zero items in it. This did not seem to fix the problem, though I appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try sending a JSON request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    // TODO: Never hardcode urls like this => always use URL helpers
    // when you want to generate an url in an ASP.NET MVC application
    url: '/AjaxServices/DashboardService/SaveDockStates',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ dockStates: dockStates }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(result) {
        // TODO: process the results
    }
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method is natively built into modern browsers. If you want to support legacy browsers you need to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Comment: @Alex Ford, your request payload is completely messed up. Where did you got this `JSON.stringify` function from? Remove it and try using the one that's built into modern browsers.

Comment: @Alex Ford, I have provided a link in my answer: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js. But as I said: first test without it => in a modern browser. As far as the url is concerned, as I said a url should ALWAYS be generated with a helper.

Comment: @Alex Ford, what browser are you using? It's impossible if you are using the latest version of Chrome. It has the JSON.stringify method built in. Make sure that you haven't overridden it somewhere.

Comment: I cannot use an mvc helper in a web form...can I?

Comment: Okay, I fixed JSON.stringify and have updated my question with the results. The request payload looks much better, but it did not seem to help the model binder.

Comment: @Alex Ford, did you include the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` setting to your AJAX request? Also why do you have `\"` in your JSON request? That still seems invalid JSON.

Comment: Yes I did, let me paste the new function. http://pastebin.com/7nYsm9y2 As far as `\"` goes, I am not sure. Could it be because they are quotes within quotes because the entire array property is in quotes, as well as individual properties within the array?

Comment: @Alex Ford, you still have an invalid request payload. Some double quotes in the beginning don't have `\` and some do have. This means that they are escaped whereas they shouldn't be. I suspect that you still have some remnants of code that interferes with JSON.stringify. Take a look at the following demo for an example of a correct way: http://jsfiddle.net/jyAnf/

Comment: Hmmmm, okay. I guess I'll keep hunting. I am not sure where the problem could be.

Comment: @Alex Ford, try like this: http://jsfiddle.net/87Xy4/. Obviously you should adapt the for loop and instead of using quotes use the real values.

Comment: Bingo, found the culprit. It was an old mootools library. I'm not sure how I'm going to remove that since it has to stay for backward compatibility, but I will worry about that later. After commenting out the script the stringify worked properly and the model binding did as well. Thanks Daron! If you don't mind, can you explain why this helped the model binder do it's job? Again, thank you.

Comment: @Alex Ford, ASP.NET MVC 3 has a built-in JsonValueProvider which allows for JSON requests. The default model binder chokes on lists of complex objects sent with jQuery. With JSON you can send arbitrary complex objects. Take a look at Phil Haacks blog post which is about ASP.NET MVC 2: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx