# mapping ajax data in c# using object binder

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The following screen shot shows the data I'm sending (shown with firebug in firefox).
The code below then shows the method the ajax method calls.  The Date and Id properties are correctly populated when hitting the server side method call but my array (of type CustomerRequests) has no values inside it, however the number of CustomerRequests in the post is correct.

Any ideas?
Thanks

[image]

My Controller method

```
   public ActionResult Show(Customers request)
   {
     .. 
     // Number of request.CustomerRequests is correct
     // Although request.CustomerRequests[0].Name == null ?? which is wrong
```

Customers class below:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customers
{

    [DataMember]
    public CustomerRequests[] CustomerRequests{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }  // I can see this value 

    [DataMember]
    public int Id{ get; set; }  // I can see this value

}



[DataContract]
public class CustomerRequests
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript

```
 $('textarea').each(function () {

   var theName = 'The Name';
   var theExpression = 'The Expression';

   var obj = {
                'Name': theName,
                'Expression': theExpression
             };

   expressionArray.push(obj);

});  // close each


// val is the posted data

var val = {
             'Id': '1',                        
             'Date': '2013-10-10',
             'CustomerRequests': $.makeArray(expressionArray)
          };
```

I've tried although it doesn't work.

```
JSON.stringify({ Customers: val })
```

Comment: I'd like to confirm the comment inside your action: `request.CustomerRequests.length` is 3 (according to the screenshot) but their properties are empty. Is that correct? Btw, well formated and complete question, congrats.

Comment: yes, although the third element is not visible in the screen shot the Show(Customers request) has request.CustomerRequests = 3

Comment: I *believe* that, on the page inspector, values should be on the format `"My Name"`. Javascript may be treating them as objects. Could you show your javascript code?

Comment: Could you try the solution provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234844/trouble-model-binding-a-json-array-to-a-list-in-asp-net-mvc-3?

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work for you

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$.makeArray(expressionArray)` with `JSON.stringify(expressionArray)`?

Comment: if I do that it nulls out the entire array so that doesnt work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32098/discussion-between-james-radford-and-andre-calil)

Comment: James, could you provide any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, we just have to add a `content-type` to your call and to remove the name from `data`.
It's something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/controller/action',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(viewModel)
});
```

Please note that:

- hard coding the URL is a bad practice. You should use `@Url.Content("")` or something like that
- `JSON.stringify` may not work with older browsers. You may need to add this lib: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not exactly an answer, because I have never used the built-in serializers, I can advise you to use the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library. I've been using it now for a long time, and I like it very much.

As for your question, I would try using `List<T>` instead of array, and I would probably try to instantiate the `List` in the constructor of the model. But these are just guesses, to be honest.

Comment: the Customers object is used everywhere so I can't change the collection :(

Comment: Actually, the default model binder for ASP.NET MVC works with arrays. I don't see any reason to change it to `List<>` if you don't need it. It would be just an overhead to your process.